# Jquery DataTable Event is not calling

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, datatables

I am using jquery DataTable. Table is working fine. I mean load records correctly. Now what I want is, I need to filter records like 
e.g I have many records in DataTable and I want to filter(custom) records that will shows only positive numbers for particular cols.

So, For that I have created below function.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        alert('51');
        if (myFilter.val() == 1)
            return true;
        else if (myFilter.val() == 2)
            return (aData[3].indexOf('-') == -1);
        else
            return (aData[3].indexOf('-') != -1);
    }
);
```

but I don't know why it is not calling. I want to call this function. I have used server side processing method for binding. I know that this method will be called when bind (draw).

I have call this function everywhere like,

a) inside $(document).ready, 
b) After DataTable config setting 
c) outside $(document).ready

And, generally I recreated DataTable manually.

```
 var oTable = $('#DataGrid').dataTable();                
            oTable.fnDestroy();
            $('#DataGrid').empty();

Tblheader = '<thead><tr><th> <select id="myFilter" class="select-filter"><option value="1">All</option> <option value="2">Positive</option> <option value="3">Negative</option> </select></th> </tr>      <tr><th rowspan="2" style="width: 5%;">Excl.</th><th rowspan="2">CUC</th> <th rowspan="2" > Late Model </th><th colspan="2">' +
                'Test1 </th><th colspan="2"> Test 2 </th> <th rowspan="2"> Test 3 </th><th id="thQtyParts" class="clsQtyParts" colspan="12" align="center"> Test 4 ' +
                                              '</th> <th rowspan="2"> Test 87 </th> <th rowspan="2"> Test 5 </th> <th colspan="4" align="center"> <input id="btnSurplus1" type="button" value="Positve" style="width: 100px;" /> Test 6 </th> <%--<th> &nbsp; </th>--%> ' +
                                              '</tr> <tr> <th> Test 7 </th> <th> Test 8</th><th> Test 8 </th> <th>Test 9</th><th> 12 </th> <th>11</th> <th> ' +
                                              '10 </th> <th>9 </th> <th> 8 </th> <th> 7  </th> <th> 6 </th>' +
                                              '<th> 5 </th>  <th>4 </th> <th> 3</th>  <th>2 </th> <th> 1  </th> <th> Test 22 </th> <th> test 23</th> <th>' +
                                              ' Test 11</th> <th> test 12</th> <%--<th>  &nbsp; </th>--%>   </tr> </thead>';

            $("#DataGrid").append(Tblheader);

            if (val == "Test Model") {

                $("#DataGrid").DataTable({
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                   /* "sDom": 'fltip', */
                    "sAjaxSource": '<%= Url.Action("GetTestData") %>',
                    "sServerMethod": "POST",
                    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                        aoData.push({ "name": "ID", "value": $("#ddl1").val() },
                    { "name": "strCatg", "value": $("#ddlCat").val() })
                    },
                    "aoColumns": [{ sWidth: '1%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
                    { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { "targets": [10], "visible": false, "searchable": false }, { "targets": [11], "visible": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "targets": [12], "visible": false, "searchable": false }, { "targets": [13], "visible": false, "searchable": false }, { "targets": [14], "visible": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "targets": [15], "visible": false, "searchable": false }, { "targets": [16], "visible": false, "searchable": false }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
                    { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%'}],
                    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
                        setTimeout(function () { $.loader('close'); }, 1000);
                    }
                });
```

Thanks 
-Nimesh

Comment: you forgot **d) _before_ the dataTable is initialised!** This it will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution.
I have create one function like on Test button onclick in

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
                    $("#Grid").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
                    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {                    
                        /* You code goes here */ 
                    });
                });

});
```

This work fine for me.